# Do we have a detailed whitepaper available for Snowflake which includes in depth explanation on the architecture choices?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Do we have a detailed whitepaper available for Snowflake which includes in depth explanation on the architecture choices? Similar to how Google BigQuery has the Dremel whitepaper.

Synapse, Snowflake, BigQuery and RedShift are very similar in their architecture. I am trying to do a detailed analysis on the subtle differences in their architectures and features.

Answer (score 2):

SIGMOD 2016, “The Snowflake Elastic Data Warehouse”:

- https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/2882903.2903741
- https://www.snowflake.com/resource/sigmod-2016-paper-snowflake-elastic-data-warehouse/

> We decided a fundamental redesign was in order. Our mission was to build an enterprise-ready data warehousing solution for the cloud. The result is the Snowflake Elastic Data Warehouse, or “Snowflake” for short. Snowflake is a
> multi-tenant, transactional, secure, highly scalable and elastic system with full SQL support and built-in extensions for semi-structured and schema-less data. The system is offered as a pay-as-you-go service in the Amazon cloud. Users upload their data to the cloud and can immediately manage and query it using familiar tools and interfaces. Implementation began in late 2012 and Snowflake has been generally available since June 2015. Today, Snowflake is used in production by a growing number of small and large organizations alike. The system runs several million queries per day over multiple petabytes of data.

> In this paper, we describe the design of Snowflake and its novel multi-cluster, shared-data architecture. The paper highlights some of the key features of Snowflake: extreme elasticity and availability, semi-structured and schema-less
> data, time travel, and end-to-end security. It concludes with lessons learned and an outlook on ongoing work.

Comment: Thanks Felipe, exactly what i was looking for. Do you know if there is detailed documentation around the qualitative / design differences between Snowflake, BigQuery, Synapse and RedShift?

Comment: BigQuery: "We have this internal tool at Google, let's create APIs so other people can use it". Redshift: "Let's scale PostgreSQL for analytic workloads". Snowflake: "Let's start a data warehouse from zero, built on and for the cloud". (I'm paraphrasing here, and I don't know much about Synapse)